# How to show a check_box selected, after a form submission? Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails4. I am searching the product via search-form. This form redirects to the same page with results. How can I show the selected check_box_tag after the form submission?

```
<%= form_tag(products_path(params[:sub_category_id]), :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
         <%= check_box_tag :diamond%> Diamond
         <%= check_box_tag :gemstone %> Gemstone
         <%= check_box_tag :pearl %> Pearl

      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>


    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check_box_tag` accepts boolean value as third argument, which states if it is checked or not. In your case this should do:

```
     <%= check_box_tag :diamond, "1", params[:diamond] %> Diamond
     <%= check_box_tag :gemstone, "1", params[:gemstone] %> Gemstone
     <%= check_box_tag :pearl, "1", params[:pearl] %> Pearl
```

(The second parameter is `value` and one is default, see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

Comment: That's weird. I just checked locally and everything works fine. Could you post some more info? Best would be "parameters" fragment from log, like this: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "diamond"=>"1", "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"111"}`

Comment: Sorry @katafrakt.... I tried it at wrong place earlier. Thank you so much... its working perfectly fine. :)